# How to make a parent with child where it can only select 1 child per parent in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

here's the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mcqxk-tikynx?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-select-hide-selected',
  template: `
    <nz-select nzMode="multiple" nzPlaceHolder="Inserted are removed" [(ngModel)]="listOfSelectedValue">
      <nz-option
        *ngFor="let option of listOfOption"
        [nzLabel]="option"
        [nzValue]="option"
        [nzHide]="!isNotSelected(option)"
      ></nz-option>
    </nz-select>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      nz-select {
        width: 100%;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class NzDemoSelectHideSelectedComponent {
  listOfOption = ['Project 1', 'Project 2', 'Project 3', 'project 4'];
  listOfSelectedValue: string[] = [];

  isNotSelected(value: string): boolean {
    return this.listOfSelectedValue.indexOf(value) === -1;
  }
}
```

[image]

what I want to do here is, when you select the "Project 1" there's another column or child which it will select what group it is, for example group 1 or group 2 or group 3, but it can only choose 1 group and selecting the item, it can select another project same as the "Project 1" it has a group where it select where it belong if group 1 or group 2 or group 3.

output should be like this: 
[image]

Comment: Your last paragraph is confusing. Can you create a hard-coded mockup in your stackblitz?

Comment: @KurtHamilton similar to selecttree

Comment: similar to this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2gdtwm?file=src/app/app.component.ts but it only select 1 from the child and the parent shouldn't be selectable. only the child can be select

Comment: Firstly, you're probably better off using that control then. The documentation looks pretty good and it looks configurable https://ng.ant.design/components/tree-select/en. If you're still struggling, you should post questions about ng-zorro on the [ng-zorro-antd] tag. This isn't a general Angular or Javascript question.